# How does DNS work for mail server? And how to check MX and A record?

Tags: networking, email, dns

I have read up on DNS which basically means that it translate my domain name into an ip address. So just to confirm when i do a nslookup on cmd, i get e.g

On my PC (NOT CONNECTED TO INTERNET, LOCAL NETWORK):

```
Default server: ps4.example.org --> this is my fully qualified DN?
Address: 1.2.3.4 --> this is my preferred DNS ?
```

My main objective is to create a DNS to direct traffic between 2 PCs. I do not understand how MX and A record works even after reading up. And how do i check it?

**Update: Just to clarify, i have an internal IP add and a DNS server(preferred DNS in the settings). What is this DNS server referring to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nslookup is a program that lets you query information about domains. This information must come from a DNS server.

When you type nslookup into the command prompt, it starts the nslookup program and initialise the default DNS server to ps4.example.org with associated IP address of 1.2.3.4. This is the DNS server that will answer your subsequent queries about domains.

To check for MX record, you supply nslookup program with more commands

```
set type=mx
google.com
```

Similarly, to check for A record,

```
set type=a
google.com
```

You can read up more about what [nslookup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525) does.

You do not have to use DNS per-se if it is just for your home network. You can use the [computer name](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4e31cbf5-0331-4023-a664-78f99a80ae57/can-connect-to-shared-folder-via-computernamefolder-name-but-not-ipfolder-name?forum=winserverPN) if you do not want to use IP. Otherwise, you have to read up on DNS servers instead of DNS records.

Comment: So what does it mean if i am checking for the mx record of google.com?

Comment: For beginners, you might want to think that domain and IP are just names that identify a particular server. When you check the MX, it gives you a bunch of domain and IP. This just tells you what are the servers that manage Mail Exchange for anyone@google.com email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

result you posted above means:

ps4.example.org - this is FQDN (fully qualified domain name) for the DNS server
1.2.3.4 - this is DNS IP address

In other words, this is the destination which gives you answer to your DNS requests. Instead of using DNS you can simplify your solution and use /etc/hosts (linux) or "lmhosts" file (windows, however I'm not sure about this one).
As far as MX records: this is something which you can not handle in above mentioned files, you will need to set up your own DNS.